# WINRM configuration blocked by GPO

Tags: windows, ansible, winrm, gpo

I'm trying to configure my windows machine to use WINRM and communicate with ansible. Among the steps I need to set allowUnencrypted to true. But I got this error :

> Set Item : The config setting AllowUnencrypted cannot be changed because is controlled by policies. The policy needs to be set to "Not Configured" in order to change the config setting.

Is there any workaround to make ansible work without this configuration? or should I just make a request to the AD team to change the GPO ?